# Convolution of a signal by itself

Tags: signal-analysis, linear-systems

I'm studying for a test and I can't really explain this question very well.

What will happen If we convolve a discrete signal signal with itself?
(Output signal )
I'll appreciate it if someone can explain this concept to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a little too vague to be answered here, too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A **signal** does not have the properties *time-invariant, linear, stable, casual*
that you wish to ascribe to it; these are properties of *systems.*  Properties
of signals that might be of interest include

- bounded amplitude versus unbounded amplitude
- discrete amplitude versus continuous amplitude
- discrete-time versus continuous-time
- periodic versus nonperiodic
- finite energy or finite power or neither
- single frequency versus multi-frequency
- finite bandwidth versus infinite bandwidth
- baseband versus passband

and possibly others.

Thus, your question is pretty much unanswerable.